# Shiny Data Download

Tags: r, shiny

Following the link here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html I edited the code to get this,

```
ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(

  # Input: Choose dataset ----
  selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
              choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

  # Button
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

),

# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel(

  tableOutput("table")

)

)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

# Reactive value for selected dataset ----
datasetInput <- reactive({
  switch(input$dataset,
         "rock" = rock,
         "pressure" = pressure,
         "cars" = cars)
})

# Table of selected dataset ----
output$table <- renderTable({
  datasetInput()
})

download = function(filename,data){
  downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste(filename, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(data,file,row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

# Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
output$downloadData <- download(input$dataset,datasetInput())

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The only difference being the download handler was moved into a function. If we run the app it works but only for the first download. The file name and data seem to get cached when the dataset is changed for a second download. If the app is refreshed a different dataset may be downloaded but only for the first time again.

Is this a variable scoping issue or a bug. The code works fine as given in the link above. The behavior just seemed strange.

Comment: That's weird code, do you really need that ? Having said that, I would try to put `output$downloadData` inside an `observe({})`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I couldn't get this to work with `observe()`. Maybe you could show how? I'm curious.

Comment: @MrFlick You gave the answer I roughly had in mind when typing this comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your download function call evaluates it's parameters so they are no longer reactive. If you really want to do this, I supposed you'd have to observe the dataset input. Something like this

```
observeEvent(input$dataset, {
  output$downloadData <- download(input$dataset,datasetInput())
})
```

Comment: Wouldnt this evaluate everytime input$dataset changed and not when the download button was pressed?

Comment: Yes. it will change the download handler each time the dataset changes. That way when the button is pressed. The right handler will already be set up. If you try it, you should see that it works.

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, why isn't the original example evaluated just once? I guess download handler is not a reactive environment?

Comment: You are just registering a handler. The `filename` and `content` functions are not run until the button is pressed. But when you call your `download()` function, you are fixing the values. They will not be any different later because they are evaluated. But when the function has `input$dataset` inside, then that value will change over time.